# Issues accessing Ubuntu through vnc

Tags: vnc

I have installed through a SSH console into my Ubuntu server a service called vncserver and I ran it. This is the output:

```
New 'X' desktop is ubuntu-s-4vcpu-8gb-fra1-01:3

Starting applications specified in /root/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /root/.vnc/ubuntu-s-4vcpu-8gb-fra1-01:3.log
```

When I try connecting remotely on my Mac through the screen sharing app, I use the link vnc://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5903 but the connection won't establish. (Where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the server's public IP). Any help?

Comment: Is your intent to have a desktop on your server?

Comment: @OrganicMarble No, my intent is being able to access such desktop from a remote computer.

Comment: AFAIK you must run a desktop on the server in order to remotely access a desktop on the server.  If that is not what you wish to achieve, you are headed down the wrong path.

Comment: `vncserver` should be fine on a headless server (it's not a "desktop sharing" type of VNC like `vino` or `x11vnc`). Unless your server is directly connected to the internet, you will need to forward port 5903 across the router in order to connect to it via a public IP. However it would be better to *tunnel* the VNC traffic via an SSH connection, since an open VNC port on the internet will almost certainly be subjected to brute-forcing attacks (since VNC authentication is inherently weak).